# I tried coonect to webdriver but why this error is coming?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.parseLogOutput(DriverService.java:468)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.loadSystemProperties(ChromeDriverService.java:291)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:491)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:157)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at Sachin/com.Sachin.TestCase.main(TestCase.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 6 more
```

Connected Google chrome and open chrome

Comment: Check Selenium and WebDriver Versions: Ensure that you are using compatible versions of Selenium WebDriver and its associated drivers (e.g., ChromeDriver, GeckoDriver). Mismatched versions can lead to compatibility issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.parseLogOutput(DriverService.java:468)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.loadSystemProperties(ChromeDriverService.java:291)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:491)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:157)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at pkmnMoom/pkmnMoom.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

I had put all of my external jars in the module path instead of the class path.
Switched them over and it ran fine. Hope this helps.